# c# reflection on ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, observablecollection

We're reflecting a .net dll that is a silverlight dll:

```
Type:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[product.entity.Customer]
```

How to handle the '1?

The observable collection is declared like this:

```
ObservableCollection<product.entity.Customer> list = new ObservableCollection<product.entity.Customer>();
```

Where product.entity.Customer is just a POCO.

My question is not around the POCO but the reflection with the '1.

How to determine when/how to reflect the object held by the observable collection?

```
...
existingTypes = loadedAssembly.GetTypes();
...
flags_plus = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public |    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

propertyInfo = type.GetProperties(flags_plus);
...
propertyInfo.PropertyType had the '1 in it...
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `GetGenericTypeArguments()` to see the list of types passed as type parameters.